# поиск через PDO

Tags: pdo, php_pdo, php, mysql, поиск

Всем доброго времени суток.
Суть проблемы:

```
$find = '%fish%';
$db = new PDO(подключаемся);
$sth = $db->prepare("SELECT id, title, url FROM news WHERE title LIKE ?");
$sth->execute(array($find));
$articles = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

возвращает массив Array ( [id] => 12 [title] => fish fish fish [url] => ss.com ).
Но только одну строку, а не все со схожими вхождениями (которые есть точно).
Пробовал и биндвалуе и биндпарам перед экзекьютом, но безрезультатно.
Единственный действенный вариант был:

```
$articles = $db->query("SELECT id, title, url FROM news WHERE title LIKE ".$find."");
```

но так ведь не кошерно :с

```
$sth = $db->prepare("SELECT id, title, url FROM news WHERE title LIKE ?");
$sth->execute(array($find));
$articles = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Так тоже возвращает первую строку с вхождением. Рад любым комментариям.

Comment: вместо $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); поробуйте использовать $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$articles = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`

вы вытащили 1-ую строку результата.

возможно вам нада сделать вот так

```
while($articles = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {  
    // тут делаем что нада с результирующим набором
}
```

Comment: о, да, получилось! благодарю! а я выводил через форич и как-то не пошло

Comment: через форич не пошло потому что fetch по 1 записи достает. Тут либо fetch и while либо fetchAll и foreach

Answer (score 2):

```
$sth = $db->prepare("SELECT id, title, url FROM news WHERE title LIKE ?");
$sth->execute(array('%'.$find.'%'));
$sth-> setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
while($row = $sth->fetch()){
   //
}
```

Comment: вот такое находил во многих примерах, но такой запрос мне вообще ничего не возвращает.
upd: прошу прощения, не заметил. возвращает единицу.

Answer (score 2):

`$articles = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`

Comment: пустой массив возвращает

Comment: `

    $sth = $db->prepare("SELECT id, title, url FROM news WHERE title LIKE ?");
    $sth->execute(array($find));
    $articles = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

`

Если возвращает пустой массив, то проверьте запрос без условия. Увидите, всё будет работать так, как и должно.

Comment: Этот метод, вроде бы, не всегда есть. То ли он, то ли какой-то другой от mysqlnd зависит, и у меня, лично, не работал по дефолту.